# Functions and loops

Tags: arrays, function, loops, autoit

I am trying to make the function `_EncryptionProcess()` take arrays 1 by 1 and process them. I realized you can't have functions inside `For` loops.

The location in which the arrays need to be taken is where `$aArray` is typed, the arrays are stored in this value. The other variable defines the key size and value.

```
;Cuts the input up into piece; 
$VariableToBeCut = "12345678"
$aArray = StringRegExp($VariableToBeCut, ".{2}", 3)
MsgBox(0, "die", $aArray[0]) ; personal check to make sure array works

$DataToBeEncrypted=_EncryptionProcess($aArray, $keyvalue, $keysize, 1) ;$aArray needs to be where the different arrays are processed
MsgBox(0, "Encrypted data", $DataToBeEncrypted)
```

Comment: You can have functions within arrays. You just cant define them there. Do you fully know how to use functions?

Comment: I would like to think that i know how to use functions but can you please help me on this problem

Comment: What language is this? It looks like PHP except the ; comments.

Comment: @EvanCarslake The language used in the question is AutoIt script.

Comment: @bahjat What do you mean by "can't use functions in loops"? Of course you can call a function inside of loops in AutoIt.

Comment: Where is the code with the for loop included? the first `MsgBox()` returns the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should process array elements.

```
;Cuts the input up into piece;
$VariableToBeCut = "12345678"
$aArray = StringRegExp($VariableToBeCut, ".{2}", 3)

ConsoleWrite("Array element 0: " & $aArray[0] & @LF) ; personal check to make sure array works

For $i = 0 To UBound($aArray)-1

    $DataToBeEncrypted = _EncryptionProcess($aArray[$i], $keyvalue, $keysize, 1)

    ConsoleWrite("Element " & $i & " : " & $aArray[$i] & " DataToBeEncrypted: " & $DataToBeEncrypted & @LF)

Next
```